# iPython prompt confusion

Tags: ipython, prompt

I am having trouble getting the prompt to show the current working directory in iPython 0.13.1 running in windows.  As you can see below, after changing the current working directory to `'C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\loutilities'`, the `\Y3` only shows `'C:/Users/Lou'`.  The same behavior is seen with `\w` and `{cwd}` configurations.

I'm sure this is something dumb I'm doing, but I haven't been able to figure it out, or find anything through Google or Stack Overflow.

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-9572.json

C:/Users/Lou> cd "C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\loutilities"
C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\loutilities

C:/Users/Lou> config PromptManager
PromptManager options
-------------------
PromptManager.color_scheme=<Unicode>
    Current: u'Linux'
PromptManager.in2_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'   .\\D.: '
    Continuation prompt.
PromptManager.in_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'\\Y3> '
    Input prompt.  '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
PromptManager.justify=<Bool>
    Current: False
    If True (default), each prompt will be right-aligned with the preceding one.
PromptManager.out_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'Out[\\#]: '
    Output prompt. '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
```

Thomas asked for output of `os.getcwdu()`.  I used config command to change the prompt (I'd gone back to `In [#n]` prompt), and `In [#n]` prompt remained.  A clue?

```
In [1]: config PromptManager.in_template='\\Y3'

In [3]: config PromptManager
PromptManager options
-------------------
PromptManager.color_scheme=<Unicode>
    Current: u'Linux'
PromptManager.in2_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'   .\\D.: '
    Continuation prompt.
PromptManager.in_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'\\Y3'
    Input prompt.  '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
PromptManager.justify=<Bool>
    Current: True
    If True (default), each prompt will be right-aligned with the preceding one.
PromptManager.out_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'Out[\\#]: '
    Output prompt. '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number

In [4]: import os

In [5]: os.getcwdu()
Out[5]: u'C:\\Users\\Lou'

In [6]: cd weather
(bookmark:weather) -> C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\weather
C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\weather

In [7]: os.getcwdu()
Out[7]: u"C:\\Users\\Lou\\Documents\\Lou's Software\\projects\\weather"
```

And the original test duplicated...

```
C:/Users/Lou> cd weather
(bookmark:weather) -> C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\weather
C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\weather

C:/Users/Lou> import os

C:/Users/Lou> os.getcwdu()
      Out[3]: u"C:\\Users\\Lou\\Documents\\Lou's Software\\projects\\weather"

C:/Users/Lou> config PromptManager
PromptManager options
-------------------
PromptManager.color_scheme=<Unicode>
    Current: u'Linux'
PromptManager.in2_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'   .\\D.: '
    Continuation prompt.
PromptManager.in_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'\\Y3> '
    Input prompt.  '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
PromptManager.justify=<Bool>
    Current: True
    If True (default), each prompt will be right-aligned with the preceding one.
PromptManager.out_template=<Unicode>
    Current: u'Out[\\#]: '
    Output prompt. '\#' will be transformed to the prompt number
```

11/21/12 - check `get_ipython().prompt_manager.templates`:

```
C:/Users/Lou> pwd
      Out[1]: u'C:\\Users\\Lou'

C:/Users/Lou> get_ipython().prompt_manager.templates
      Out[2]:
{'in': u'{cwd_y[3]}> ',
 'in2': u'   .{dots}.: ',
 'out': u'Out[{color.number}{count}{color.prompt}]: '}

C:/Users/Lou> cd weather
(bookmark:weather) -> C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\weather
C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\weather

C:/Users/Lou> pwd
      Out[4]: u"C:\\Users\\Lou\\Documents\\Lou's Software\\projects\\weather"

C:/Users/Lou> get_ipython().prompt_manager.templates
      Out[5]:
{'in': u'{cwd_y[3]}> ',
 'in2': u'   .{dots}.: ',
 'out': u'Out[{color.number}{count}{color.prompt}]: '}
```

Comment: Can you replicate the problem, then check what `os.getcwdu()` returns? I'm puzzled by this. For reference, the code `\Y3` uses is here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/prompts.py#L219

Comment: I updated the original question with the experiment results.  Seems like the PromptManager.in_template is evaluated only once at the startup?

Comment: It should be re-evaluated - it is when I do the same thing. Either the problem is Windows specific, or your installation is broken somehow. Can you replicate it again, and see what `get_ipython().prompt_manager.templates` contains?

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- no way to get notified when comments are made?  Anyway, I checked `get_ipython().prompt_manager.templates`, and results are on the bottom of original question.  Thanks for supporting this.

Comment: OK, that's showing what it ought to, at least. Can you [file a bug report](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues?state=open) with these details? It looks like there is a bug, and the issue tracker is a better interface to work that out.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Will do so tomorrow.

Comment: Further discussion at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2614